# how to stop the matplotlib GUI thread from freezing up?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, matplotlib

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as p
from scipy import zeros
from Queue import Queue
import random

w,h = 320,200

black = zeros((h,w,3), dtype='uint8')
red = black.copy(); red[:,:,0] = 255
green = black.copy(); green[:,:,1] = 255
blue = black.copy(); blue[:,:,2] = 255

def ants():
  from scipy import rand, dstack
  return dstack([(255*rand(h,w)).astype('uint8')]*3)

fig = p.figure()
axs = [fig.add_subplot(1,3,i) for i in xrange(3)]
[ax.imshow(black) for ax in axs]

q = Queue()

def update_image(ax):
  ## this takes some time
  import time
  time.sleep(3)
  ax.images[0].set_data(random.choice([red, green, blue]))

def hit(event):
  if event.inaxes in axs:
    update_axs = [event.inaxes]
  else:
    update_axs = axs
  for ax in update_axs:
    ax.images[0].set_data(ants())
  p.draw()
#  for ax in update_axs:
#    update_image(ax)
#  p.draw()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', hit)
p.show()
```

here is my code, which all works as expected.  however when i uncomment those 3 lines in the event handler, there are some problems i didn't expect.  first of all the GUI freezes up while `update_image` is working , and secondly the first call to `draw()` does not seem to get a chance to paint because i don't see the racing ants while `update_image` is working.  what is a better way to setup this kind of thing in matplotlib so it works smoothly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid freezing the GUI, you need to run `update_image` in a separate thread or process. Using `threading`, you might do something like this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as p
from scipy import zeros
import random
import threading


w,h = 320,200

black = zeros((h,w,3), dtype='uint8')
red = black.copy(); red[:,:,0] = 255
green = black.copy(); green[:,:,1] = 255
blue = black.copy(); blue[:,:,2] = 255

def ants():
    from scipy import rand, dstack
    return dstack([(255*rand(h,w)).astype('uint8')]*3)

fig = p.figure()
axs = [fig.add_subplot(1,3,i) for i in xrange(3)]
[ax.imshow(black) for ax in axs]

def update_image(ax):
    ## this takes some time
    import time
    time.sleep(3)
    ax.images[0].set_data(random.choice([red, green, blue]))
    ax.figure.canvas.draw()

def hit(event):
    if event.inaxes in axs:
        update_axs = [event.inaxes]
    else:
        update_axs = axs
    for ax in update_axs:
        ax.images[0].set_data(ants())
    p.draw()
    for ax in update_axs:
        t=threading.Thread(target=update_image,args=(ax,))
        t.daemon=True
        t.start()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', hit)
p.show()
```

Comment: thankyou, i was trying something similar already with `Queue`..so it's nice to know i was on the right track.  your version above works , but it also has some strange behaviour.  the `draw()` in the worker thread doesn't seem to have any effect until there is a GUI event in the figure window, e.g. a mouse move event.  it updates as expected with `ipython -pylab`, but this seems to cause instability - lots of clicks can cause the ants to persist and even the figure window to crash!  is there some mechanism other than `p.draw()` needed here to cause the figure window to repaint appropriately?

Comment: @wim: That's a great question. Thank you for pointing it out. It appears that if you declare `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` then the axes are updated (without mouse events) when `ax.figure.canvas.draw()` or `p.draw()` is called. There are probably other solutions (like using gtk, wx, qt, or other backends?) but I don't know the complete answer.

Comment: thanks again for the answer.  switching from GTKAgg to TkAgg backend resolved the issue.  out of curiousity, do you know if it is strictly allowed to call draw() from within the worker thread?  it works okay on my local machine, but when i try to use it over an `ssh -Y` session, i get `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop` caused by the line `ax.figure.canvas.draw()`.  however if i let the parent thread do the `draw()` after worker threads `join()` then there is no problem.  the remote machine and local machine have exactly the same python/matplotlib/backend setup.

Comment: @wim: You're question is great, but it's pushing me into territory I don't know a lot about. It seems possible that `ax.figure.canvas.draw()` or `p.draw()` should not be called from the thread. Assuming that's true, I added some code showing how you could work around this using a `do_redraw` flag and `gobject.idle_add`... but I have strong doubt that this is the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: @wim: I've finally had a chance to test the script (with and without `gobject.idle_add`) through ssh. I see it doesn't work, though I don't know why. (In my case, I didn't get a RuntimeError -- the GUI didn't draw anything but the buttons at the bottom of the window...) Sorry, I simply don't know the answer.